# linux ftp lcd error No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ftp

I wrote a bash script to connect to an ftp server and download files from the FTP server to different directories on my local linux box.

I am using the following to achieve this.

```
#! /bin/sh 
FILENAME='helloworld.txt'
USSER='username'
PASSWD='password'
ftp -niv ftp.domain.com <<HEREDOC
quote USER $USSER
quote PASS $PASSWD
lcd /home/username/scripts/data
mget $FILENAME
bye
HEREDOC
```

I had to use USSER to login because USER is a keyword

Also, I was able to manually run the commands without any error.

Does anyone know what the issue could be? Any help with this or leads on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

When I run the script, I get the following and notice how the error message covers up most of the path that it is echoing

```
# bash test.sh
test.sh: line 11: warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wan')d `HEREDOC
Connected to ftp.domain.com (ipaddress).
220 Welcome to the domain FTP Server
331 Password required for username.
230 User username logged in.
: No such file or directoryts/data
local: helloworld.txt remote: helloworld.txt
227 Entering Passive Mode (216,19,206,212,226,85)
150 Data connection accepted from myipaddress:54375; transfer starting for /helloworld.txt (107828 bytes)
226 File sent ok.
107828 bytes received in 0.137 secs (789.81 Kbytes/sec)
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: Does `/home/username/scripts/data` in fact exist on the system on which you run this script? I just reproduced your script (with different filename, user, password, site, etc. obviously), and it worked fine....

Comment: @twalberg Yes. I can connect, change local directories, and download manually without errors, but when running a script file is when I get the error. Notice that the error overlaps/writes over the path.

Comment: @twalberg Could it be the way my system is setup? Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the error message is overwriting itself is that your filename is included in the error message, and a carriage return is included in your filename. You need to `dos2unix` that thing and stop editing unix scripts with DOS-ish editors.